# Design a thread-safe Hit Counter

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, lock-free

I have designed a Hit Counter which can conveniently be used to design a Rate Limiter
Original question: https://leetcode.com/problems/design-hit-counter/

To make it thread safe, I used [lock statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock).

```
public class HitCounter {
  private readonly int duration = 300;
  private readonly int[] hits, times;
  //https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock
  private readonly Object lockObj = new Object();
  public HitCounter(int duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
    times = new int[duration];
    hits = new int[duration];
  }

  public void Hit(int timestamp) {
    var idx = timestamp % duration;
    lock (lockObj){
      if(times[idx] != timestamp){
        times[idx] = timestamp;
        hits[idx] = 1;
      }else{
        hits[idx]++;
      }
    }
  }

  public int GetHits(int timestamp) {
    var res = 0;
    lock (lockObj){
      for(var i = 0; i < duration; ++i){
        if(timestamp - times[i] < duration){
          res += hits[i];
        }
      }
    }
    return res;
  }
}
```

My questions are:

- Is it just about surrounding the part which the two arrays are accessed with locks
- Isn't it better to use ConcurrentDictionary as an index-array? To make it lock-free

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why do you use 3 different namings for 3 private readonly fields?

Comment: Also why did you tag it with asynchronous?

Comment: Just as an FYI - `ConcurrentDictionary` does lock internally but it creates multiple locks so that you can access different keys concurrently (as long as they aren't sharing a lock).

Comment: @PeterCsala what do you mean by 3 different naming?

Comment: @DanielB DURATION, hits, _lockObject

Comment: @PeterCsala what do you suggest? Any better ways have in mind?

Comment: @DanielB The `DURATION`, which should be a `const` instead of `readonly`, I would suggest PascalCasing: `Duration`. For the `private readonly` fields I would suggest camelCasing: `hits`, `lockObject`

Answer (score 3):

For this design, making it threadsafe is just about using a lock statement to allow just one thread to modify the data structure at a time. This implementation is fine and appears to be correct. Depending on how it's used, there might be some improvements, such as checking `times[idx] <= timestamp` to avoid rolling back if some data arrives late. It's a little odd to assign `duration` a value of 300 in the initializer when the only constructor requires the caller to provide a value.

Like many people, I consider "parallel arrays" to be an anti-pattern. They have their uses, but those are the exception. I would suggest making this a single array of a two-int object. Either a `Tuple`, or you could even define your own class for better readability. One thing that would let you do is to lock on just the entry you are modifying, rather than having a single lock for the whole data structure. Note that you do still need to lock; what you want to prevent is uncoordinated modification of the hit counter. Even if you use Interlocked.Increment, you still have a race with the thread assigning 1 to it.

You mention ConcurrentDictionary - using that class leaves you still needing to solve this same problem of uncoordinated modification of the values. ConcurrentDictionary means that you can modify the dictionary structure without locking, it doesn't solve race conditions with how you use the values. If you imagine how a solution using ConcurrentDictionary would look, you would probably build it in the constructor and then never Add or Remove keys - but adding or removing values is the whole reason for using a ConcurrentDictionary.